# Accessing shared drive with DriveApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a new file in a shared drive using google apps script so that other people using the shared drive can also access the file. Is there a method on DriveApp that allows me to do that?

I have tried using DriveApp.getFoldersByName but this is for the root folder in my private drive only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You need to use the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) based on the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/)

The method [Drive.Drives.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) allows you to specify the Drive Id.

> Keep in mind that for shared drives, you need to specify the
>   additional parameter `supportsAllDrives: true`. Also, you need to [enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) the Advanced Drive Service before using.

Sample:

```
function myFunction() {  
  var optionalArgs={supportsAllDrives: true};
  var resource = {
    title: 'mySharedFile',
    mimeType: 'application/pdf',
    parents:[{
      "id": "ID OF THE SHARED DRIVE"
    }]
  }  
  Drive.Files.insert(resource, null, optionalArgs)
}
```