# Create New Folder and Save SHEET1 to the New Folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, save-as

I've found scripts that created a new folder and save a copy of a spread sheet to the new folder.

1. I'd like to save SHEET1 only but I could not figure it out
2. The script creates new folder folder in My Drive => but I would like to create fhe new folder in SHARE DRIVE / NEW CLIENT

```
var ss               = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var dest_folder_name = ss.getRange('A1').getValue();
var copy_name        = ss.getRange('A2').getValue();

var dest_folder      = "";
var file_id          = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
var file             = DriveApp.getFileById(file_id);
var parent_folder    = file.getParents().next();
var sub_folders      = parent_folder.getFolders();

// search a destination folder in current folder
while (sub_folders.hasNext()) {
    dest_folder = sub_folders.next();
    if (dest_folder.getName() === dest_folder_name) {
        break;
    }
    dest_folder = "";
}

// create the destination folder if nothing was found
if (dest_folder === "") {
    dest_folder = parent_folder.createFolder(dest_folder_name);
}

// copy the spreadsheet to the destination folder
file.makeCopy(copy_name, dest_folder);
```

Regards,
tt3

Comment: Are there 2 questions in your question? By the way, I cannot understand about your 2nd question of `It create folder in My Drive => and I would like to create folder which I know the folder ID (SHARE DRIVE/NEW CLIENT/new folder here)`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I meant I know the folder ID of “New Client” but I don’t know the folderid of “new folder” => create new folder inside existing folder name “New Client”. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about `It create folder in My Drive => and I would like to create folder which I know the folder ID (SHARE DRIVE/NEW CLIENT/new folder here)`. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: The script creates new folder folder in My Drive => but I would like to create fhe new folder in SHARE DRIVE / NEW CLIENT

Comment: The simple way is to place the source file to the root folder where I want to create a new folder  =>  I still need HELP of part one: HOW TO COPY SHEET1 only

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that 2 answers had already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Spreadsheet URL by replacing `/edit#gid=somegidhere` with /export?gid=somegidhere and download using `FetchApp` [fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) and use `DriveApp` [createFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfileblob) to upload file.

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {

    
  var dest_folder_name = "66794562"
  var dest_folder      = "";
  var file_id          = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var file             = DriveApp.getFileById(file_id);
  var parent_folder    = file.getParents().next();
  var sub_folders      = parent_folder.getFolders();

  // search a destination folder in current folder
  while (sub_folders.hasNext()) {
      dest_folder = sub_folders.next();
      if (dest_folder.getName() === dest_folder_name) {
          break;
      }
      dest_folder = "";
  }

  // create the destination folder if nothing was found
  if (dest_folder === "") {
      dest_folder = parent_folder.createFolder(dest_folder_name);
  }

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = sh.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var spreadsheetId = sh.getId();
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();

  var url           = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+spreadsheetId+'/export?gid='+sheetId;
  var token         = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response      = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });

  var fileName = 'copyofSheet1';
  var blob   = response.getBlob().setName(fileName);
  dest_folder.createFile(blob);

}
```

**Source:**

[image]

**Destination:**

[image]

**Content:**

[image]

Comment: @@Niikko: The scripts worked. Is there any way to modify the scripts create the new folder in this ==> Share Drive / New Client / "new folder here"  ?

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

**The first part of your question:** 
Similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170053/accessing-shared-drive-with-driveapp).

**The second part of your question:**
As far as I have understood you have the file id of your destination spreadsheet and you know the source sheet's name. Then try this:

```
function copyToSpreadsheet(){

 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Your Spreadsheet ID");
 var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("SheetX");

 var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Destination ID');
 sheet.copyTo(destination);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the link and simple way is to place the source file to the root folder where I want to create a new folder.  I still need HELP of part one: HOW TO COPY SHEET1 only