# Search files in shared Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have the problem.

Earlier I had the file for search in my own Google Drive. And the script worked.

```
function checkInFiles(){

  var nameJSON = 'jobToCAF';

  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "' + nameJSON + '"');

  while (files.hasNext()) {
     var file = files.next();
     Logger.log(file.getName());

  }
}
```

Script searches for files named like `0080076042_jobToCAF.JSON`.

The difference is that now the file is located in shared Google Drive and search doesn't work.

Can you help ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing shared drive with DriveApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170053/accessing-shared-drive-with-driveapp)

Comment: check the question I marked as duplicate

Comment: @J. G. may be this is right answer but there is some different. the file format is json. What I must to set in mimeType:? and the search is by part of name of file, the file always uploads from one resource and don't have static id. How can I decide it?

Comment: @Kos may be in your resource there is the way to resolve the issue... I saw that I can get the TeamDrive.items like the array with data, and may be I can get one of this elements by searching by the part of name. It's just my thoughts, I wil try this way. What do you think about it?

Comment: function printMimeType(){
var gdrive = "xxxxxxx";
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(gdrive);
console.log(file.getMimeType());
} is what you should use to find out the mimetype string for a json file, mimetype strings are usually something  like     "'application/cab',
    'text/html', if I had to guess I would say json is going to be text/json but better to check a known file and be sure.

Comment: thank you, but Kos gave me success way)