# Google Drive - search Shared drives

Tags: google-apps-script, search, drive

quite a newbie on this so forgive me if this is stupid.
In my team we have Shared drives for every single project which leaves me with over 150 shared drives now. I would like to add/build/use a search function for those shared drives which works in the same way as searching for documents.
Any suggestions where I can begin my search?

Comment: google apps script reference

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170053/accessing-shared-drive-with-driveapp
 is a question on accessing shared drives.
ziganotschka answered "You need to use the Advanced Drive Service based on the Drive API"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Google Apps Script, you will have to make use of the Drive Advanced Service as the `DriveApp` class does not provide a method of working with shared drives. The Drive Advanced Service is nothing but a wrapper for the Drive API v2.

Therefore, what you want can be achieved by writing a function similar to this for searching the files in a shared drive for which you already have the id:

```
function searchDrive(sharedDriveId) {
  let optionalArgs = { supportsAllDrives: true };
  let resource = {
    q: "title = 'TITLE_TO_SEARCH_FOR'"
    parents: [{
      "id": sharedDriveId
    }]
  }
  let results = Drive.Files.list(resource, null, optionalArgs);
  return results;

}
```

As for listing all the shared drives, the `Drive.Drives.list()` can be of help in this situation.

#### Reference

- [Drive Advanced Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive);
- [Drive API v2 Files:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list);
- [Drive API v2 Drives:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/drives/list).