# Google Apps Script from My Drive to Shared Drives

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have designed a feedback system via Google Sheets and Apps Script. It works all good on My Drive. When I moved it to a Shared Drive, the "DriveApp" didn't like the change.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170053/accessing-shared-drive-with-driveapp) very useful article that John from Google shard with me, I activated [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) and used the method **Drive.Drives.insert** allows you to specify the Drive Id.

How can I specify a folder in a shared drive with this method? Like the one we have with DriveApp (DriveApp.getFolderByID). How would you do that?

Comment: By guessing your goal, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `How can I specify a folder in a shared drive with this method? Like the one we have with DriveApp (DriveApp.getFolderByID). How would you do that?`, I guessed that you might want to retrieve the folder information. If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script 1:

When you can know the folder ID of the folder in a shared Drive, you can use the following script. Before you use this, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.

```js
const folderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID in a shared Drive.

// This sample uses Drive service (DriveApp).
const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
const folderName1 = folder.getName();
console.log(folderName1)

// This sample uses Drive API.
const obj = Drive.Files.get(folderId, {supportsTeamDrives: true});
const folderName2 = obj.title;
console.log(folderName2)
```

- In this sample script, the folder name of the folder is in a shared Drive using Google Apps Script. This script includes 2 patterns. Please confirm it.
- In the case of DriveApp, when the file ID and folder ID are used, the files and folders in a shared Drive can be retrieved.

#### Sample script 2:

When you cannot know the folder ID of the folder in a shared Drive, you can use the following script.

```js
const driveId = "###"; // Please set your Drive ID.

// This sample uses Drive service (DriveApp).
const folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(driveId).getFolders();
while (folders.hasNext()) {
  const folder = folders.next();
  const folderName1 = folder.getName();
  console.log(folderName1)
}

// This sample uses Drive API.
const res = Drive.Files.list({ corpora: "drive", includeItemsFromAllDrives: true, supportsAllDrives: true, driveId, q: `mimeType='${MimeType.FOLDER}' and trashed=false` });
res.items.forEach(({title}) => console.log(title));
```

- In this script, in the case of DriveApp, the folder list is retrieved from just under the top folder of the shared Drive. Please be careful about this.
- In the case of Drive API, the folder list of all folders in the shared Drive is retrieved. But, this is a sample script. So, in this case, 100 folders can be retrieved. When you want to retrieve more, please set `maxResults` and `pageToken`. Please be careful about this.

#### Note:

- These sample scripts are simple scripts. So, please modify them for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [getFolderById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid)
- [Files: get of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get)
- [Files: list of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list)